# build mongodb driver (visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mongodb

Is it possible to build the mongodb driver as shared library under visual studio 2012? Couldn't find anything in the docs.

When i build it as static lib it is over 200MB in size (release build) => doesn't seem right

Anyone knows if there are efforts to build another c++ driver with no dependencies? (there is a c-driver for which this is the case)

Comment: "doesn't seem right" what makes you think that?

Comment: @PlasmaHH it's just the driver. i fear higher link times => want a shared library